# tidyr separate column values into character and numeric using regex

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I'd like to separate column values using `tidyr::separate` and a regex expression but am new to regex expressions

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("enc0","enc10","enc25","enc100","harab0","harab25","harab100","requi0","requi25","requi100"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

This is what I've tried

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   separate(A, c("name","value"), sep="[a-z]+")
```

Bad Output

```
   name value
1           0
2          10
3          25
4         100
5           0
# etc
```

How do I save the `name` column as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may  use a `(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])` lookaround based regex with `tidyr::separate`:

```
> tidyr::separate(df, A, into = c("name", "value"), "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])")
    name value
1    enc     0
2    enc    10
3    enc    25
4    enc   100
5  harab     0
6  harab    25
7  harab   100
8  requi     0
9  requi    25
10 requi   100
```

The `(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])` pattern matches a *location* in the string right in between a lowercase ASCII letter (`(?<=[a-z])`) and a digit (`(?=[0-9])`). The `(?<=...)` is a positive lookahead that requires the presence of some pattern immediately to the left of the current location, and `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead that requires the presence of its pattern immediately to the right of the current location. Thus, the letters and digits are kept intact when splitting.

Alternatively, you may use `extract`:

```
extract(df, A, into = c("name", "value"), "^([a-z]+)(\\d+)$")
```

Output:

```
    name value
1    enc     0
2    enc    10
3    enc    25
4    enc   100
5  harab     0
6  harab    25
7  harab   100
8  requi     0
9  requi    25
10 requi   100
```

The `^([a-z]+)(\\d+)$` pattern matches:

- `^` - start of input
- `([a-z]+)` - Capturing group 1 (column `name`): one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `(\\d+)` - Capturing group 2 (column `value`): one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more step If you really want to get it with `separate`, in which I don't see the point, i.e. (Using the same regex as @ WiktorStribiżew),

```
df %>% 
  mutate(A = gsub('^([a-z]+)(\\d+)$', '\\1_\\2', A)) %>% 
  separate(A, into = c('name', 'value'), sep = '_')
```

Answer (score 1):

For a bare R version without a lookaround-based regex, define the regular expression first:

```
> re <- "[a-zA-Z][0-9]"
```

Then use two `substr()` commands to separate and return the desired two components, before and after the matched pattern.

```
> with(df,
      data.frame(name=substr(A, 1L, regexpr(re, A)), 
                 value=substr(A, regexpr(re, A) + 1L, 1000L))
      )
    name value
1    enc     0
2    enc    10
3    enc    25
4    enc   100
5  harab     0
6  harab    25
7  harab   100
8  requi     0
9  requi    25
10 requi   100
```

The regex here looks for the pattern "any alpha" `[a-zA-Z]` followed by "any numeric" `[0-9]`. I believe this is what the `reshape` command does if the `sep` argument is specified as "".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package *unglue*

```r
library(unglue)
unglue_unnest(df, A, "{name=\\D+}{value}")
#>     name value
#> 1    enc     0
#> 2    enc    10
#> 3    enc    25
#> 4    enc   100
#> 5  harab     0
#> 6  harab    25
#> 7  harab   100
#> 8  requi     0
#> 9  requi    25
#> 10 requi   100
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>