# Split string on both sides of a number

Tags: r, split, strsplit

Let's say we have strings like these:

```
data
X3Y
X33U
Y231Z
```

I want to split `data` into three columns `first.letter`, `number`, `last.letter`, so in this case:

```
first.letter number last.letter
X            3      Y
X            33     U
Y            231    Z
```

I could extract the first and last character of the column value using `substr` and then use a regular expression to extract the number but this seems really cumbersome, is there a quicker way to achieve this?

Comment: Browsing posts tagged both [tag:r] and [tag:regex] might help find related questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45591387/5325862)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    extract(data, into = c("first.letter", "number", "last.letter"),
            "^([A-Z])(\\d+)([A-Z])$")
#  first.letter number last.letter
#1            X      3           Y
#2            X     33           U
#3            Y    231           Z
```

Or with `separate`

```
df1 %>%
  separate(data, into = c("first.letter", "number", "last.letter"), 
         sep= "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])")
#   first.letter number last.letter
#1            X      3           Y
#2            X     33           U
#3            Y    231           Z
```

---

Or another option is `strsplit` and then `rbind`

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(df1$data, 
        "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(data = c("X3Y", "X33U", "Y231Z")), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
df[, tstrsplit(sub("([0-9]+)", "_\\1_", data) , "_")]


   V1  V2 V3
1:  X   3  Y
2:  X  33  U
3:  Y 231  Z
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea with minimum regex can be,

```
i1 <- gsub('\\D+', '', df1$data)
i2 <- strsplit(df1$data, '\\d+')

setNames(data.frame(t(mapply(c, i2,i1))), c('first_letter', 'second_letter', 'number'))

#  first_letter second_letter number
#1            X             Y      3
#2            X             U     33
#3            Y             Z    231
```